# Vector Euclidean norm upper bound by his coordinates average.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, machine-learning, bayesian, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to extend the Rademacher complexity and have the following question:

For $ (v_1,..,v_m) = V \in {\mathbb{R}}^{m} $ , I will be glad to find an upper abound for the Euclidean norm:

$$ ||V|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m}} v_{i}^{2} $$

That somehow involves the average of its coordinates:

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}v_i}{m}$$

More specifically my problem is to bound this expression:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}
   \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{ {S}^{'} \sim {\mathcal{D}}^{m}} \Big[  
   \mathop{sup}_{ w \in {\mathbb{R}}^{n_1} }  \Big( ||\hat{f_w}(z)|| \Big)  \Big]
   \leq \beta $$

Such that $\beta\;$ is a function of $\;\; \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}\hat{f_w}(z_i)}{m}$

And the notations is as follows:
 $$ \hat{f_w}(z_i) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{ \gamma \sim q_{w^{*}}(\gamma)} \big[ f((w,\gamma),z_i) \big] $$
$$q_{w^{*}} (\gamma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e ^{- \frac{(\gamma - w^*)^2}{2}}$$
$$S = {\lbrace z_i \rbrace}_{i=1}^{m} $$
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but the first part makes me think that you might just want the AM-QM inequality.

Comment: It gives a lower bound, and I'm looking or upper bound